# Thumbs Up/ Thumbs Down Radio Button Voting

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, forms

This seems like a popular topic but I can't seem to find anything that works the way I want... so here goes nothing:

Ideally I just want to replace my radio button with a "Green Thumbs Up" image and a "Red Thumbs Down" image... I will have a for that has a list of 10 items and each item will have a yes or no (thumbs up or down) image. They then click "vote" and it goes to a php processing page to get the information.

I am having a hard time with just replacing the radio circle with the image. I need it to be a no-selected image and a selected image. So when you first load the page they are all light images then if they click to vote it changes to a darker image. If they change their vote then it changes which image this is.

Does this make sense? Ideally I would like to just use CSS and have something like a "class="vote_yes"" but it doesn't appear that it is that easy... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that it could work the way you want if you use labels ...

`<input id="blah_1" type="radio" name="blah"><label for="blah_1"><img src="thumbup.png"></label>`
`<input id="blah_2" type="radio" name="blah"><label for="blah_2"><img src="thumbdown.png"></label>`

... and then use jquery `onchange` to do `$('blah_1').addclass('thumbup_off');` etc. Then you just hide your inputs (or at least move them offscreen).

Here are a few solutions that do it in other ways...

http://www.99points.info/2010/07/youtube-style-ratingvoting-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-ever-best-tutorial/

http://www.technabled.com/2009/02/reddit-style-voting-with-php-mysql-and.html